# Getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while calling REST Multi part for bigger size binary file upload

Tags: java, jersey

**I am trying to call java REST based service to upload binary file(70 MB) using MULTIPART. It is successfully working for 60 MB file but whenever i am exceeding the size of file getting below mentioned exception at client console:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.net.www.http.PosterOutputStream.write(PosterOutputStream.java:78)
    at `enter code here`com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:90)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeTo(ReaderWriter.java:115)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeTo(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:76)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider.writeTo(FileProvider.java:103)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider.writeTo(FileProvider.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartWriter.writeTo(MultiPartWriter.java:218)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartWriter.writeTo(MultiPartWriter.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:300)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:213)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:568)
    at
```

**I have tried with jvm arguments but no luck.**

Please help

Comment: What JVM parameters you have tried?

Comment: I have used  -Xms512m -Xmx512m in tomcat server

Comment: I got solution, apart from JVM arguments, need to provide maxpostsize="0" in tomcat's server.xml                      <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" maxpostsize="0"/>

Answer (score 0):

I think you use `new File()` to get the file data but it's better to use InputStream:

```
InputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
String sContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName.getName()+"\"";
WebResource fileResource = a_client.resource(a_sUrl);       
ClientResponse response = fileResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                        .header("Content-Disposition", sContentDisposition)
                        .post(ClientResponse.class, fileInStream);
```